# How do you inflate dynamically created objects in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, view, dynamically-generated

I've looked at most of the other threads but I can't figure out what is causing my application to crash. I keep getting "attempt to invoke virtual method Android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int) on a null reference object. This error occurs at line 25 or

```
"View ObjectView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_biking,container,false); "
```

How do you inflate a view for a newly created object in Android?
Thank you.

```
    public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View ObjectView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_biking,   container, false);
            final EditText input1 = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.input);
            final ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView)getView().findViewById(R.id.scrolling);
            Button addbox = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.CheckBoxAdd);
            addbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    for (int box = 0; box <25; box++){
                    CheckBox newcheckbox = (CheckBox)getView().findViewById(R.id.NewCheckBox);
                    newcheckbox.setText(input1.toString());
                    scroll.addView(newcheckbox);
                    }
                }
            });



            return ObjectView;
        }
}
```

Here is the xml

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
       <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       </EditText>
       <Button
        android:id="@+id/CheckBoxAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Checkbox" />
       <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/scrolling"    
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
       <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout2"
        android:orientation="vertical"> 
        </LinearLayout>

       </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getView returns the View you inflated in onCreateView, before it returns null. In your code you have two options, the first is to use `ObjectView.findViewById`, to look for the view you need. The latter is to override `onViewCreated`, and use the first parameter, which in turn is the view you returned in `onCreateView`, to look for the view you need

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code that produces the desired result.

```
package fragments_for_app;
import android.app.adventureprototype.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    LinearLayout layout;
    CheckBox newcheckbox;
//18
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View ObjectView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_biking, container, false);
        final EditText input1 = (EditText)ObjectView.findViewById(R.id.input);
        layout = (LinearLayout)ObjectView.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout2);
          //final ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView)ObjectView.findViewById(R.id.scrolling);
        final Button addbox = (Button)ObjectView.findViewById(R.id.CheckBoxAdd);
        layout.removeAllViews();
        addbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


                    newcheckbox = new CheckBox(ObjectView.getContext());
                    newcheckbox.setText(input1.getText().toString());
                    layout.addView(newcheckbox);    


                    //work on this thursday


                }
        });

          return ObjectView; 
    }

}
```